# Laravel 5.4 laravel.log permission issue

Tags: php, laravel-5, mamp-pro

I have Laravel 5.4 installed on my Mac using Composer and MAMP Pro. The installation completed successfully, but when I try to load localhost/lsapp/public, an UnexpectedValueException error is returned. I have checked the file permissions for the storage and logs directories and both are set to 755 using the command line. It seems the log file cannot be written for some reason. Any suggestions?

**Full permission denied message: The stream or file "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/lsapp/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied
in StreamHandler.php (line 107)**

Comment: hi, tried to give it permission 777 for the log directory?

Comment: Try give 777 permission to the storage file recursively.

Comment: Permissions of 777 worked, but this is not suitable for a production environment. What would be the solution for a remote server?

Answer (score 0):

When you go into a production environment, I'd recommend the following:

**755 permissions for the /log**

**644 permission for the files inside**

For example if you're using apache:

> The user owner of the directory (www-data) can read, write and execute.
>   The assigned group (www-data, where my user is) can read and execute, but not write.
>   Everyone else can read and execute, but not write.

Comment: Thanks. I would definitely use 755 for directories and 644 for files on production. Do you know why 755 was not working on localhost?

Comment: Because the folder is probably owned by your _User_ and the  _Apache_ process was trying to write the file, which is may not have permissions unless it's apart of the _User_ group.

Answer (score 0):

I just faced the same issue with my installation.  Here's what I did to solve it:

Make sure that www-data (or your web server's user) is either the owner or group's owner of the logs directory.

Then make sure that this user have read-write-execute on that folder.  On linux I used 770 for that folder. Then laravel is now working fine.

Hope that's help!